# Copying an array is swapping days/months in (seemingly) random cells

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA (as in, about 2 weeks).

I'm defining an array in one sheet and then copying it to another iteratively (that's necessary for what I intend to be doing with it later, this code is just for checking that it works properly).

When it finishes running, my array is copied, but several (seemingly random) cells have days/months switched around. E.G. 06/01/1984 has become 01/06/1984

This is the code:

```
Sub Define_Arrays()

Dim Wsh As Worksheet

Dim FTSE100(1 To 1592, 1 To 5) As String
Dim row_A As Integer
Dim column_A As Integer

' Define FTSE 100 Array

Set Wsh = sheet2
Wsh.Activate

row_A = 1
column_A = 1

For row_A = LBound(FTSE100, 1) To UBound(FTSE100, 1)

    For column_A = LBound(FTSE100, 2) To UBound(FTSE100, 2)

    FTSE100(row_A, column_A) = Cells(row_A, column_A)

    Next column_A

Next row_A

' Print FTSE 100 Array

Set Wsh = sheet1
Wsh.Activate

For row_A = LBound(FTSE100, 1) To UBound(FTSE100, 1)

    For column_A = LBound(FTSE100, 2) To UBound(FTSE100, 2)

    Cells(row_A, column_A) = FTSE100(row_A, column_A)

    Next column_A

Next row_A

End Sub
```

The original array looks like this

```
Date (GMT)  Open    High    Low Last
06/01/1984  997.5   1029.3  993.3   1029
13/01/1984  1034.6  1042.7  1020.2  1042.7
20/01/1984  1046    1060.6  1036.2  1059
27/01/1984  1046.8  1075.9  1039.9  1075.9
03/02/1984  1068.6  1082    1046    1059.8
10/02/1984  1038.2  1054.2  1010    1018
```

And the output looks like this

```
Date (GMT)  Open    High    Low Last
01/06/1984  997.5   1029.3  993.3   1029
13/01/1984  1034.6  1042.7  1020.2  1042.7
20/01/1984  1046    1060.6  1036.2  1059
27/01/1984  1046.8  1075.9  1039.9  1075.9
02/03/1984  1068.6  1082    1046    1059.8
02/10/1984  1038.2  1054.2  1010    1018
```

I cleared the date formatting for both columns and I got the following:

original:

```
Date (GMT)  Open    High    Low Last 
30687   997.5   1029.3  993.3   1029
30694   1034.6  1042.7  1020.2  1042.7
30701   1046    1060.6  1036.2  1059
30708   1046.8  1075.9  1039.9  1075.9
30715   1068.6  1082    1046    1059.8
30722   1038.2  1054.2  1010    1018
```

Output:

```
Date (GMT)  Open    High    Low Last
30834       997.5   1029.3  993.3   1029
13/01/1984  1034.6  1042.7  1020.2  1042.7
20/01/1984  1046    1060.6  1036.2  1059
27/01/1984  1046.8  1075.9  1039.9  1075.9
30743       1068.6  1082    1046    1059.8
30957       1038.2  1054.2  1010    1018
```

Interestingly, when I run the code with the cells not date-formatted, it works absolutely fine. Any suggestions as to what's going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: When entering the date into the array, if you specify American date format (eg array(x, y) = format(cells(x, y), "mm/dd/yyyy")), it will enter the correct value for the date, then it should output into whatever date format your workbook uses.

Comment: You can also simply use `.Value2` when populating the array (assuming the source data is a real date).

Comment: @Dave that's a perfectly acceptable answer. Please post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer, as requested:

When entering the date into the array, if you specify American date format eg:

```
array(x, y) = format(cells(x, y), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

it will enter the correct value for the date, then it should output into whatever date format your workbook uses.